# NUMBER system and counting

Tags: number-theory, number-systems

Let $S =\{1,2,3,...,20\}$ be the set of all positive from $1$ to $20$ suppose that $N$ is the smallest positive integer such that exactly eighteen numbers from $S$ are factors of $N$ and the only two numbers from $S$ that are not factors of $N$ are consecutive integers. Find the sum of digits of $N$.

We first find out which two consecutive numbers from $S$ are 
not factors of $N$. Clearly $1$ is the factor of $N$.
If $k$ is not factor of $N$ then $2k$ will also be not he factor of $N$.

How will I solve further please help.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hint:  start down the possible pairs of nonfactors.  It can't be $\{19,20\}$ because then we know $4$ and $5$ are both factors, so $20$ must be. Now try $\{18,19\}$, which fails (why?).  Keep going.

Comment: Yes I got it then 16 and 17 are not the factors of N

Comment: Correct. Can you find the prime decomposition of  $N$?  Where are you stuck?

Comment: Yes 2^3×3^2×5×7×11×13×19=6846840

Comment: Is it correct....

Comment: Yes, that is correct.  Once you have $N$ you have the sum of digits.  It is interesting to try to state the condition on the pair of missing numbers based on the maximum number in $S$.